# Firebase/React - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signInWithEmailAndPassword') at RegistrarUsuario

Tags: reactjs, firebase

se me presento este error y me gustaria saber si me pueden ayudar a solucionarlo, no entiendo bien el porque me da ese error, investige por todos lados y no se porque me da undefined

> signInWithEmailAndPassword

La funcion es la siguiente:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/login.css'
import {app, auth} from '../firebaseconfig'

const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('')

    const RegistrarUsuario = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
           auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={RegistrarUsuario} action="">

            <input onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} type="text"  placeholder="Email"/>
            <input onChange={(e)=>{setPass(e.target.value)}}type="password" name="" id="" placeholder="********"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Continuar" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

La verdad es que no se porque sucede y me esta quemando el cerebro, agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Implementacion de firebase:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x-x.x.x",
  projectId: "x-x",
  storageBucket: "x-x.x.x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "1:x:web:x",
  measurementId: "x-x"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const auth = getAuth(app);

export { auth}
```

Comment: Como estas implementando tu auth de firebase? El error te esta indicando que la importación de auth es undefined. Podrías incluir esa configuración?

Comment: Listo @PauloUrbanoRivera

Answer (score 0):

Estas exportando mal los datos en tu inicialización,debes acceder simplemente a las funciones de firebase, ademas estas haciendo un login y tu funcion es un registro, Lo mas normal es exportar firebase completo y en tu componente usar lo que necesites
asi lo configuro yo:

**1.creo un archivo llamado firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase";
var firebaseConfig = {};
// Your web app's Firebase configuration

firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xx",
  projectId: "xx",
  storageBucket: "xx",
  messagingSenderId: "xx",
  appId: "xx",
  measurementId: "xx",
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

**2.en el inicio del componente importo el archivo firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "../../firebase";
const auth =firebase.auth();
```

**3.lo uso**

```
 auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.code == "auth/user-not-found") {
          registerFirebase({ email, password });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Me dice: Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\veterina\src'

Comment: tiene que  el archivo firebase js dentro de src

Comment: Claro, lo tengo ahi, en Veterinaria/src/firebaseconfig.js

Comment: pues llamalo asi igual "firebaseconfig" no firebase

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer los siguientes cambios:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "****",
    authDomain: "**",
    projectId: "**",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***"
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = fire.auth()

  export {auth}
```

Nota: ten en cuenta que el archivo que se exporta es auth

quiero añadir también un ejemplo donde se puede registrar y al iniciar sesión si los datos son validos arroja una alerta y si no aparece un error,  esto te puede ayudar adicional si llegas a tener algún inconveniente al implementar el login como tal, con esto ya debería solucionar tu inconveniente:

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {auth} from '../firebaseconfig'

function Login() {
    const[email,setEmail] = useState('')
    const[pass,setPass] = useState('')

    const RegistrarUsuario = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
           auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
           alert('Usuario registrado')
        }catch (e){
         console.log(e)

        }
    }

    const LoginUsuario = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
       auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass) 
       alert('usuario en base de datos')
        }catch (e){
         console.log(e)

        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='row mt-5'>
            <div className="col"></div>
            <div className="col">
                <form onSubmit={RegistrarUsuario}  className='form-group'>
                <input 
                onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}}
                    className='form-control'
                    placeholder="Introduce el Email"
                    type="email" />
                <input 
                onChange={(e)=>{setPass(e.target.value)}}
                    className='form-control mt-4'
                    placeholder="Introduce la Contraseña"
                    type="password" />
                    <input 
                    className="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-4"
                    value='Registrar usuario'
                    type="submit" />
                </form>
                <button
                onClick={LoginUsuario}
                  className='btn btn-success btn-block mt-4'
                >
                    Iniciar sesión
                </button>
            </div>            
            <div className="col"></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```